# Assertion not executing in Python Mock

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-mock

I'm trying to implement some unit testing on some code I am building but I'm seeing this weird behavior where even though I set the return value of a function call to be **False**, the related code does not execute and thus the assertion `instance.fail_json.assert_called_with(msg='Not enough parameters specified.')`fails.

[image: Console Output]

Is there something else I need to be setting?

project.py:

```
def main():
   # define the available arguments/parameters that a user can pass
   # to the module
   module_args = dict(
      name=dict(type='str', required=True),
      ticktype=dict(type='str'),
      path=dict(type='str'),
      dbrp=dict(type='str'),
      state=dict(type='str', required=True, choices=["present", "absent"]),
      enable=dict(type='str', default="no", choices=["yes","no","da","net"])
   )

   required_if=[
      [ "state", "present", ["name", "type", "path", "dbrp", "enabled"] ],
      [ "state", "absent", ["name"]]
   ]

   # seed the result dict in the object
   # we primarily care about changed and state
   # change is if this module effectively modified the target
   # state will include any data that you want your module to pass back
   # for consumption, for exampole, in a subsequent task
   result = dict(
      changed=False,
      original_message='',
      message=''
   )

   # the AnsibleModule object will be our abstraction working with Ansible
   # this includes instantiation, a couple of common attr would be the
   # args/params passed to the execution, as well as if the module
   # supports check mode
   module = AnsibleModule(
      argument_spec=module_args,
      supports_check_mode=False
   )

   # if the user is working with this module in only check mode we do not
   # want to make any changes to the environment, just return the current
   # state with no modifications
   if module.check_mode:
      return result

   return_val = run_module(module)
   return_val = True
   if return_val is True:
      module.exit_json(changed=True, msg="Project updated.")
   else:
      module.fail_json(changed=True, msg="Not enough parameters found.")
```

test_project.py:

```
@patch('library.project.run_module')
@patch('library.project.AnsibleModule')
def test_main_exit_functionality_failure(mock_module, mock_run_module):
   """
   project - test_main_exit_functionality - failure
   """
   instance = mock_module.return_value

   # What happens when the run_module returns false
   # that is run_module fails
   mock_run_module.return_value = False

   project.main()

   # AnsibleModule.exit_json should not activated
   assert_equals(instance.fail_json.call_count, 0)

   #AnsibleModule.fail_json should be called
   instance.fail_json.assert_called_with(msg='Not enough parameters 
   specified.')
```

Comment: This isn't really a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it's very difficult to read the code with no context. You should read through your test code very carefully to make sure it says what you think it says.

I think the main problem might be the last line. You have to pass _all_ the expected arguments to `assert_called_with`. It should read `instance.fail_json.assert_called_with(changed=True, msg='Not enough parameters 
   specified.')`

Comment: I'll go back and update the code to reflect the above standard. However, if I set the return value of mock_run_module to 'False':
```mock_run_module.return_value=False```
 
will that cause the if-else branch in main to execute false and thus subsequently run module.fail_json(changed=True, msg="Not enough parameters specified.")? Why that doesn't run is my main disconnect.

    ```if return_value is True: 
       module.exit_json(changed=True, msg=""Project updated.")
    else:
       module.fail_json(changed=True, msg="Not enough parameters found."```

Answer (score 0):

Re-read your production code. It sets return_val to True on the line before checking if it's True:

```
...

return_val = run_module(module)

return_val = True

if return_val is True:
    ...
```

`return_val` is always true no matter what `run_module` returns, so no matter what you do in your test, the production code will always execute the 'true' branch of the if-else check.